# Android Studio - Can't debug on my Device

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, installation

I'm facing this issue with multiple devices. And i have no idea how to fix that.

Whenever i try to install an app from Android Studio into my Device i ends up getting this error.

I tested this on Vivo, Mi, and some other devices but i got the same error.

Please lemme know if there's a solution to it. Or at least help to get a basic idea why this is happening to my Android Studio.

My Version of Android studio is v.2.3.1

[image: Android Studio Error/Warning]

Comment: Disable Instant Run from Settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try disabling instant run

Settings> Build, Executions,Deployment> Instant Run

Comment: Thanks a lot...It worked like a charm..I hope this bug will get fixed in the Upcoming version of Android Studio ^_^

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation points so i can't upvote the answer...but anyways..thanks a lot.. ^_^

Answer (score 3):

There are two chances:

1.USB Debugging off :

Enable Developer Option of your device,
Switch On USB Debugging

2.In Android-Studio : File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
Clean the project and rebuild the project.

Comment: Restart AndroidStudio did the trick